# distribution of $X+X$

Tags: probability, random-variables

My question is about the interpretation of the expression of $X+X$, where $X$ is a random variable.

For example, suppose $X$ is the number seen when we roll a regular six-sided dice.

Is $X+X$ the sum when we roll two dice, or is it twice the value we see on one dice?

In other words, is there a difference between the random variables $X+X$ and $2X$?

Answer (score 2):

The notation you use, $X+X$, indicates that a single realization of $X$ is added to itself to yield $2X$; thus this would represent the outcome of a single die roll, multiplied by $2$.

If you wanted to represent the outcome of two independent die rolls, that is precisely described as $$X_1 + X_2,$$ where $X_1, X_2$ are independent and identically distributed as discrete uniform random variables on the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$.

Answer (score 1):

You should use $X+Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are independent and identically distributed. Note that identically distributed does not mean identical.

Answer (score 1):

$X+X=2X$ everywhere. It is twice the value seen on 1 die.

If you want the sum of values on 2 separate die,then $S=X+Y$; $X,Y\to iid \in\{1,\cdots 6\}$